# Sending dummy data via a socket on android to java server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to send some very simple data from my android device to a server on my laptop via a socket however no data is displayed. Here is the android part: (the data is sent whenever a press a button hence why an intent)

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    try {
        Socket my_socket = new Socket(ip, 5000);
        DataOutputStream st = new DataOutputStream(my_socket.getOutputStream());
        st.write(21);
        st.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("ERROR","Something here went wrong" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the server code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
        System.out.println("Waiting for a client");
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String input_line;
        while((input_line = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(input_line);
        }
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the android that doesn't send the data or the server that doesn't receive the data as I tried sending data to the java server using an erlang socket and no data was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client should send more data to the end of line like '₩n'
For server to catch the end of line...

How about adding PrinterWriter or BufferedWriter to make client more simple.. cause they have line related methods.